# Checking if booking is possible in SQL (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, gaps-in-data

I have table booking with such looking records:

```
  id  |        from         |         to
------+---------------------+---------------------
  101 | 2015-09-24 08:00:00 | 2015-09-24 09:30:00
 2261 | 2015-09-24 09:00:00 | 2015-09-24 10:00:00
 4061 | 2015-09-24 10:00:00 | 2015-09-24 10:30:00
  204 | 2015-09-24 12:00:00 | 2015-09-24 13:30:00
 2400 | 2015-09-24 13:30:00 | 2015-09-24 14:00:00
 4224 | 2015-09-24 14:00:00 | 2015-09-24 14:30:00
  309 | 2015-09-24 16:00:00 | 2015-09-24 17:30:00
 2541 | 2015-09-24 17:00:00 | 2015-09-24 18:00:00
```

I am looking for optimal query to find anwser to question:

`Is this possible to find a timeslot with duration x (ie. 30 minutes) in above records?`

I have ideas to use postgres arrays or time ranges, but still looking for better ideas....

EDIT: I will provide 'fake' bookings as boundaries, but if you have ideas how to do it better, please write :)

Comment: The question seems incomplete.  If you have no bookings, then you cannot fine time slots.  In other words, you need to provide start and end information.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : You are right. I am currently assuming [ -infinity,+infinity ]

Comment: I edited question, thanks for notice!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
where (select min("from") from tablename t2
       where t2."from" > t1."from") >= t1."to" + interval '30' minute
```

I.e. return a row if the gap to the following row is >= 30 minutes.

**Note**: `from` and `to` are reserved words in ANSI SQL, that's why they are delimited as `"from"` and `"to"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution using analytical functions, it provides all windows with no bookings:

```
SELECT null as ts_from, min(ts_from) as ts_to
  FROM bookings
 UNION ALL
SELECT ts as ts_from, next_ts as ts_to
  FROM (SELECT ts, lead(ts, 1) over (order by ts) as next_ts, sum(bk) over (order by ts) as bksum
          FROM (SELECT ts_from as ts, 1 as bk
                  FROM bookings
                 UNION ALL
                SELECT ts_to as ts, -1 as bk
                  FROM bookings) as t) as tt
 WHERE bksum = 0
 ORDER BY 1 NULLS FIRST;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fa32e/11).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lag()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html) function:

```
select *, book_start- previous_book_end timeslot
from (
    select id, "from" book_start, "to" book_end, 
    lag("to") over (order by "to") previous_book_end
    from test
    ) sub
order by book_end

  id  |     book_start      |      book_end       |  previous_book_end  | timeslot
------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------
  101 | 2015-09-24 08:00:00 | 2015-09-24 09:30:00 |                     |
 2261 | 2015-09-24 09:00:00 | 2015-09-24 10:00:00 | 2015-09-24 09:30:00 | -00:30:00
 4061 | 2015-09-24 10:00:00 | 2015-09-24 10:30:00 | 2015-09-24 10:00:00 | 00:00:00
  204 | 2015-09-24 12:00:00 | 2015-09-24 13:30:00 | 2015-09-24 10:30:00 | 01:30:00
 2400 | 2015-09-24 13:30:00 | 2015-09-24 14:00:00 | 2015-09-24 13:30:00 | 00:00:00
 4224 | 2015-09-24 14:00:00 | 2015-09-24 14:30:00 | 2015-09-24 14:00:00 | 00:00:00
  309 | 2015-09-24 16:00:00 | 2015-09-24 17:30:00 | 2015-09-24 14:30:00 | 01:30:00
 2541 | 2015-09-24 17:00:00 | 2015-09-24 18:00:00 | 2015-09-24 17:30:00 | -00:30:00
(8 rows)
```

Select rows with `timeslots >= '30m'::interval`:

```
select *, book_start- previous_book_end timeslot
from (
    select id, "from" book_start, "to" book_end, 
    lag("to") over (order by "to") previous_book_end
    from test
    ) sub
where book_start- previous_book_end >= '30m'::interval
order by book_end

 id  |     book_start      |      book_end       |  previous_book_end  | timeslot
-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------
 204 | 2015-09-24 12:00:00 | 2015-09-24 13:30:00 | 2015-09-24 10:30:00 | 01:30:00
 309 | 2015-09-24 16:00:00 | 2015-09-24 17:30:00 | 2015-09-24 14:30:00 | 01:30:00
(2 rows)
```

Comment: You can't look at previous booking only. Imagine the first booking covers entire timespan. You willl report incorrect slots ([example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b2bd2/3)).

Comment: Sure, I can imagine everything. Perhaps a better idea would be to leave the OP assess whether such hypothetical situations can take place?

Comment: Well, I made mistake, and we can assume bookings cant overlaps (in example it does but there are some foreign keys in table).

Comment: This is consistent with how I understand the essence of booking. The query in my answer could help with avoiding such cases. Well, @Kombajnzbożowy, downvoting was a little bit premature, was not it?

Comment: Yes, with constraint of non-overlapping bookings your solution is fine. I just assumed worst case in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Non-standard self-join:

```
SELECT
    ll.ts_to AS ts_from
    , hh.ts_from AS ts_to
FROM bookings ll
JOIN bookings hh
    -- enough space 
    ON hh.ts_from >= ll.ts_to + '30 min'::interval
    -- and nothing in between
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM bookings nx
        WHERE nx.ts_from >= ll.ts_to
        AND nx.ts_to <= hh.ts_from
        )
UNION ALL   -- before the first
SELECT '-infinity'::timestamp AS ts_from
       , MIN(ts_from) AS ts_to
    FROM bookings
UNION ALL   -- after the last
SELECT MAX(ts_to) AS ts_from
       , 'infinity'::timestamp AS ts_to
    FROM bookings
ORDER BY 1,2
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate your slots and then left join them.
[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12bfa](http://sqlfiddle)

```
create table t (id integer, "from" timestamp, "to" timestamp);

insert into t values 
(101 , '2015-09-24 08:00:00' , '2015-09-24 09:30:00' ),
(2261 , '2015-09-24 09:00:00' , '2015-09-24 10:00:00' ),
(4061 , '2015-09-24 10:00:00' , '2015-09-24 10:30:00' ),
( 204 , '2015-09-24 12:00:00' , '2015-09-24 13:30:00' ),
(2400 , '2015-09-24 13:30:00' , '2015-09-24 14:00:00' ),
(4224 , '2015-09-24 14:00:00' , '2015-09-24 14:30:00' ),
( 309 , '2015-09-24 16:00:00' , '2015-09-24 17:30:00' ),
(2541 , '2015-09-24 17:00:00' , '2015-09-24 18:00:00' );

SELECT time_slots.t,
       time_slots.t + interval '30 minutes'
FROM generate_series(date'2015-09-24',date'2015-09-25' - interval '30 minutes' ,interval '30 minutes') AS time_slots(t)
LEFT JOIN t ON (time_slots.t BETWEEN t."from" AND t."to")
WHERE t.id IS NULL;


SELECT time_slots.t,
       time_slots.t + interval '30 minutes'
FROM generate_series(date'2015-09-24',date'2015-09-25' - interval '30 minutes',interval '30 minutes') AS time_slots(t)
LEFT JOIN t ON ((time_slots.t,
                 time_slots.t + interval '30 minutes') OVERLAPS (t."from",
                                                                 t."to"))
WHERE t.id IS NULL;
```